# When flying to a towered airport when the tower is closed, what frequency should I use?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications

The attached picture shows the [Rapid City Regional Airport, KRAP](http://airnav.com/airport/KRAP).  If I arrive after KRAP's tower is closed, which frequency should I use: 125.85 or 122.95?

[image: Sectional Snippet]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use the CTAF for announcing your position and intentions, i.e. 125.85. From the [AIM 4-1-9(g)](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf):

> If an airport has a tower and it is temporarily closed, or operated on
>   a part-time basis and there is no FSS on the airport or the FSS is
>   closed, use the CTAF to self-announce your position or intentions.

4-1-9(b) says:

> The CTAF may be a UNICOM, MULTICOM, FSS, or tower frequency and is
>   identified in appropriate aeronautical publications.

125.85 is marked as the CTAF on the sectional and listed in [the Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/results/?cycle=1707&ident=KRAP&navaid=).

Note: The letter "C" in the dark circle next to the control tower ("CT") frequency indicates that the CT frequency is the CTAF frequency at that airport.

Comment: Understood, and I know the CTAF is 125.85 because the blue-circled C is next to 125.85, right?  If the blue-circled C was next to 122.95, CTAF would be that frequency?

Comment: @GarrisonNeely Yes, the C indicates the CTAF frequency. You can check the [VFR chart legend](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/) for a full breakdown of all the information shown there.